# How to execute same query again in Apollo Client

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo

I have a query like this.

```
 const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(ME,{
        onCompleted: data => {
          console.log(data)
        }
      })
```

After executing this query, I can not execute this query again.
How I can execute same query twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out default fetchPolicy is "cache-first". I need to turn off like this.

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(ME,{
    onCompleted: data => {
      console.log(data)
    },
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'
  })
```